# Sort with multiple keys meteor mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor, mongodb-query

I've collection named invoice, I wanted to sort my collection by date but result should be invoices having invoice number should be at top and invoice without having invoice number should be at the bottom.

I have tried this but not worked.

```
Invoice.find({},{sort:{createdAt :-1, invoiceNumber: 1}})
```

Comment: Try this way `Users.find({}, { sort: [['createdAt', 'desc'], ['invoiceNumber', 'asc']] })`

Comment: tried this but not working

Comment: I have checked both the ways `Invoice.find({},{sort:{createdAt :-1, invoiceNumber: 1}})
` or `Users.find({}, { sort: [['createdAt', 'desc'], ['invoiceNumber', 'asc']] })` And both are working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible to do it just like that with a sort, as far as i know. You can try first sorting by invoiceNumber then by createdAt, but that wont give you the result you want.

For that I suggest you do 2 queries and then concat both of them into one array.

```js
const withNumber = Invoice.find({ invoiceNumber: { $exists: true } }, { sort: { createdAt :-1 }});

const withoutNumber = Invoice.find({ invoiceNumber: { $exists: false } }, { sort: { createdAt :-1 }});

const all = [...withNumber, ...withoutNumber];
```